# Using python script in ArcGIS field calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, field-calculator, python-parser

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 version in desktop. I wanted to assign landuse names (`Landuse_04` column) based on the codes those are in my attribute table as the column `ID_MAP`. once I am done with editing the script in python, field calculator, this dialogue box is appearing! I do not have any idea about python or programming just worked on a prepared script.

Does anyone know why is this occurring?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you put the defined function into the returned field. The message says if you have multi-line you have to cut the code and activate the Show codeblock and paste the code into the "Pre-Logic" Script Code space. The last line should be used to return the defined function exist in the "Pre-Logic" Script Code.

Check "Using code blocks" in the [Calculate Field examples](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DF13F7EE4AF345CAAA46C1CFA2F7BFE1) for more information.

Here is a code snippet from the above help

```
Code Block:
def Reclass(WellYield):
    if (WellYield >= 0 and WellYield <= 10):
        return 1
    elif (WellYield > 10 and WellYield <= 20):
        return 2
    elif (WellYield > 20 and WellYield <= 30):
        return 3
    elif (WellYield > 30):
        return 4


Expression:
Reclass(!WELL_YIELD!)
```